# How to initiate an action with a button?

Tags: excel, vba

In one column I have a four entries. Two of them are of one category called "TX" and the other two are "SW".

A list is made into a drop down box in cell H12 and when selected you can pick any of the four entries from the list.

When selected, you put a number under that cell (H13). When a button is clicked, and an entry of "TX" is selected, it will go in one cell (P2). If the entry selected is "SW" it will go in (Q2). As the user changes the number or the selection from the drop down, the number is added to the previous number for that category.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
    If Range("SW").Text = Range("H12").Text Then
        Range("H13").Copy
        Range("Q2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        
    ElseIf Range("TX").Text = Range("H12").Text Then
        Range("H13").Copy
        Range("P2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    
End Sub
```

When I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: "2 of them are of one category called "TX" and the other two are "SW""  - are you saying you have two named ranges "TX" and "SW" ?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. In Category TX, there are two stored entry that I have put (FTX and LTX) and in SW there are two called LSH and LSL

Comment: Question is, how VBA code could recognise "TX" and "SW": a) headlines above your columns? b) names of two cell ranges? c) text values in an adjacent column? ...?

Comment: Think of it this way: if you needed to do it manually what are the exact steps you'd take to distinguish TX from SW ?

Comment: @bmo I assumed if I made it in the Defined Names section in the Formulas tab I could reference that? As of now there is no header, just a column of information.

Comment: @TimWilliams Well, I would know from experience where each one goes. Its like a group called Fruit and Apple is in that group. When apple is selected from the drop down list and you put the number in. Clicking the button will add it to a Total Fruit cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim v, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    v = sht.Range("H12").Text

    If ValueInNamedRange(v, sht, "SW") Then

        sht.Range("Q2").Value = sht.Range("H13").Value

    ElseIf ValueInNamedRange(v, sht, "TX") Then

        sht.Range("P2").Value = sht.Range("H13").Value

    End If

End Sub

'A function to check if a value "v" is in a given named range "rangename"
'   on sheet "sht"
Function ValueInNamedRange(v, sht As Worksheet, rangename As String)
    ValueInNamedRange = Len(v) > 0 And _
         Not IsError(Application.Match(v, sht.Range(rangename), 0))
End Function
```

**EDIT**: fixed a few issues

Comment: Thanks for that Tim, I seem to get a Syntax error on 'Function ValueInNamedRange(v, rangename)' and the below two lines 

ValueInNamedRange = Len(v) > 0 And _
         Not IsError(Application.Match(v, ThisWorkbook.Range(rangename), 0)

are shown in red. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't tested - one typo and another thing fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for that Tim. Works like a charm and really easy to follow.